# Can't inject my factory in angular

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject my custom factory that look like this:

```
var tester = angular.module('tester', ['example']);

tester.controller('TesterCtrl', ['Example', function(Example) {   console.log(Example.test()); }]);

var example = angular.module('example', []);

example.factory('Example', function() {
    return {
        test: function() {
            return 'test';
        }
    };
});
```

And i get the following error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/unpr?p0=ExampleProvider%20%3C-%20Example
```

I have other custom factorys made the same way, and i can inject them with no problems.

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Qk2Raod6938aEhixz1r?p=preview

Comment: The error part is not here probably. I made a plunker for your code and it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/KfzZPXYdwYwOXUTZbWQW?p=preview
Can you provide a plunker too?

Comment: I updated with a plunker link :)

Comment: You need for the other module to declare the 'example' module as a dependency

Comment: angular.module('tester',['example'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example** service is defined within **example** module. So if you want to use **Example** service in your **tester** module, you have to define **example** module as a dependency for **tester** module.

This is a little bit confusing because of the naming you used. But you should just do as the following code.

```
angular.module('tester', ['example']);
```

Here is the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6qBJQfAD2P2hCxs0vVwF?p=info).

Comment: Ofcause! Thanks a lot for your eyes :)